# Need a SQL statement to return MAX of Computed Value grouped by common codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database with several columns.  The data looks like this:

```
Code    Time  Field_x   Field_y
--------------------------------    
Code1     0      100        50
Code1     1      123        83
Code1     2       85       112
Code1     3       74       300
Code2     0      120        52
Code2     2       12        41
Code2     4      340         0
Code3     1.2    100        50
Code3     3       45       111
Code3     5       66       -41
Code3     6.3    300       105
```

etc.

`Field_1` and `Field_2` are used to compute a value. They are in the same table.

```
Computed = 0.34*Field_1 + -0.65*Field_2
```

The same 0.34 and -0.65 are used for every Code(i) set of values.

What I would like get, in this example, would be 3 lines of results that would be the time and value associated to the maximum computed value of each group.  So Code1 would have a result, Code2 a result, Code3, etc.

In this short example the results would be:

```
Code1    0      1.50
Code2    4    115.60
Code3    5     49.09
```

I thought it would be as simple as

```
SELECT 
    Time, MAX(0.34 * Field_1 + -0.65 * Field_2) 
FROM 
    Table  
GROUP BY 
    Code
```

but I get a error stating I can't use MAX that way.

Comment: Which flavour of DBMS? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ???

Comment: And how are you choosing the `Time` value to display for the output rows?

Comment: First, thanks for the reformatting my input to a much more readable format!  I am using SQL Server, not sure about the time question.

Comment: In your example results, you have `Time` values of 3, 4, and 5, I don't understand how those values are chosen?

Comment: Sorry Nick, I understand your question now.  The row selected is a result of the highest computed value of each code(i).  So for code1 the row with Time=0 has a calculation of  0.34*100+-0.65*50 = 1.5 is the largest number of that group.  By the way, I corrected an error from my original post, so maybe that threw you off?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (0.34*Field_1 + -0.65*Field_2) as computed_value,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by (0.34*Field_1 + -0.65*Field_2) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If there are ties for the maximum on a given code, this returns an arbitrary row.  If you want all rows with the maximum, then use `rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

EDIT:

For the maximum and the minimum just use two sequence numbers:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (0.34*Field_1 + -0.65*Field_2) as computed_value,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by (0.34*Field_1 + -0.65*Field_2) desc) as seqnum_max,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by (0.34*Field_1 + -0.65*Field_2) asc) as seqnum_min
      from t
     ) t
where 1 in (seqnum_min, seqnum_max);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  That worked perfectly!  However, I misread my requirements and must have two rows returned for each code, the maximum AND minimum.  Can I window twice, using two OVER functions and select one DESC and the other ASC?  I tried it but am having trouble structuring the statement properly.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon!  Once more that is exactly what I needed!